How to flash program in ESP32-S3?
I build a custom board using ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R2. I gave a two pin jumper for boot pin.

and my reset switch is,

This is my USB Section,

What I did is,

Shorted the Boot connector
Connected the USB Cable
Press the reset switch and released while holding the boot pin to low
Release the boot connection

But I got a problem like,
USB Not recognized..

and my device manager shows
Unknown USB device(Device Descriptor request failed)

Always USB not be detected. I cannot flash my board. Please give guidence to flash program to my board!

There is not enough of the schematic to see exactly what you have done but ensure that pins EN and GPIO0(boot) are pulled high at boot time. Module Datasheet/Schematic: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf but also look at an example which uses native USB: https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/SeeedStudio-XIAO-ESP32S3/res/XIAO_ESP32S3_SCH_v1.1.pdf . When you get the USB device not recognised error, the port is usually blocked until a restart of your PC.

GPIO46 is also significant and not shown.
